# How can I have the NEWS displayed in the html help page of an R package?

Tags: r

The help page of the `news()` R function says:

> it is attempted to read its news in structured form from files
>   ‘inst/NEWS.Rd’, ‘NEWS’ or ‘inst/NEWS’ (in that order).

Doing so and installing the package, we get (under windows) a link to the NEWS file at the top of the html page open by the command  `help(package=packagename)`. For an example, assuming you have installed `party`, you can try

```
help(package="party")
```

This works however only with files named NEWS. When we provide instead a NEWS.Rd file, there is no link to the news. Try

```
help(package="survival")
```

Is there a way to get this link when we provide a NEWS.Rd file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm.  I think I confirm this result (using RStudio for HTML help rather than Windows). You can generate the HTML yourself with `tools::Rd2HTML`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the link.  If you don't get any answers here in a day or two, I would try asking on `r-devel@r-project.org`, after scouring the manuals and double-checking everything a few times to minimize your chances of getting Ripleyed ...

Comment: I brought that up with Duncan M a few weeks ago and as I recall the consensus was that yes, it was a bug and yes, it will get fixed.

Comment: Thanks. So I will wait for R 3.0.

Comment: I confirm the fix is listed under the Changes in the R-devel section in http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-devel.html and current R-devel will become R 3.0.0

Comment: @Gilbert, why not add that as an answer and accept it to show others that it has been answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved since R 3.0.0.

It seems, however, that a series of the Rd formatting code such as `\code{}` for example are ignored when rendering the NEWS.Rd in html.